# send file using java NIO selector

Tags: java, file, client, nio, server

I am trying to send file from server using java NIO selector key, but from the client side I receive the whole file when I shutting down the server.

Code for server side

```
    public static int DEFAULT_PORT = 1234;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fileName = "10mb.txt";
    int port;

    try {
        port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        port = DEFAULT_PORT;
    }
    System.out.println("Listening for connections on port " + port);

    ServerSocketChannel serverChannel;
    Selector selector;
    try {
        serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        ServerSocket ss = serverChannel.socket();
        InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(port);
        ss.bind(address);
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        selector = Selector.open();
        serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    while (true) {

        try {
            selector.select();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }

        Set readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) iterator.next();

            try {

                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    ServerSocketChannel server = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
                    SocketChannel client = server.accept();
                    System.out.println("Accepted connection from " + client);
                    client.configureBlocking(false);
                    SelectionKey key2 = client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

                    String filePath = (fileName);
                    File file = new File(filePath);
                    int fileSize = (int) file.length();
                    System.out.println("File size =" + fileSize);
                    FileInputStream fis;
                    ByteBuffer buffer = null;

                    try {
                        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                        FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
                        buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(fileSize);
                        try {
                            fc.read(buffer);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            System.out.println("IO EX :" + ex);
                        }
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        System.out.println("FileNotFoundEx :" + ex);
                    }

                    buffer.flip();
                    key2.attach(buffer);

                } else if (key.isWritable()) {

                    SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
                    ByteBuffer out = (ByteBuffer) key.attachment();

                    client.write(out);
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("IO Exeption :" + ex);
                key.cancel();
                try {
                    key.channel().close();
                } catch (IOException cex) {
                    System.out.println(cex);
                }
            }
            iterator.remove();

        }

    }

}
```

Code for client side

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fileName = "10mb.txt";
    int bufferSize = 2048;
    int n = 0;
    int read = 0;

    SocketChannel socket = SocketChannel.open(new InetSocketAddress(1234));
    String filePath = (fileName);

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
    FileChannel file = out.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


    while ((read = socket.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        buffer.flip();

        file.write(buffer);

        n = n + read;

        buffer.clear();

        System.out.println(n);
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long difference = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println("File with " + n + " bytes downloaded in " + difference + " ms");
    socket.close();

    file.close();

    out.close();
}
```

I appreciates your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming that `fc.read()` fills the buffer, and that `sc.write()` empties it. Neither assumption is valid. The correct way to copy between channels in Java is as follows:

```
while (in.read(buffer) > 0 || buffer.position() > 0)
{
    buffer.flip();
    out.write(buffer);
    buffer.compact();
}
```

As you're outputting to a `SocketChannel` in non-blocking mode you will need to modify this for the case where `write()` returns zero: if that happens, you need to register the channel for OP_WRITE, return to the `select()` loop, and resume this loop when `OP_WRITE` fires: this time, if `write()` returns non-zero, deregister `OP_WRITE`.